# How To Treat Any File As PHP In Windows IIS 7?

Tags: windows, iis, php, iis-7

I want **.any** file (could be **.this** or **.that** etc.) to be treated as a .php file and parse .php code on my windows 2008 server running IIS 7.

How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Though this may not be a concern for you, you are setting yourself up for an astoundingly large security hole.

Comment: @Zephyr Pellerin: how so? What would I have to worry about simply making a .html file parse php code? If I did so on a dedicated server that only I can access?

Comment: LFI and RFI come to mind as problems, if you truly are the only one who has access its not a problem but god forbid it ever goes production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a while since I did this, but the process last time was something like this:

1. Start>control panel>administrative
   tools>Internet Information Service
2. Choose the website you want to
   change (typically the default site)
   and then open the properties.
3. Home Directory tab, make sure
   execute permissions are set to
   "Scripts and Executables" then go to
   Configuration
4. Here you click add, then you add the
   extension for all request types.
   Give the path to php.exe.

You might have to restart iis afterwards.

Comment: Thanks pehrs , but as for number 2 - open properties? Do I right click? I don't see any "properties" value listed anywhere for any site - default or not ?

Comment: Or 3? What do you mean by the home directory tab? I'm using IIS 7.

Comment: Oh, sorry, If you are on IIS 7 it's something like

Features View panel, then Handler Mappings

see 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240%28WS.10%29.aspx